# Where's this walkable cliff in Gros Morne National Park?

Tags: identify-this, newfoundland

Note the humans standing at the edge. How do I get to this cliff? From [Newfoundland Labrador Tourism's Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bv4jKjXJWqj/)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following appears to be the location in Google Earth (unfortunately the aerial photography is hazy). This view is from above the northern shore of Western Brook Pond.

It looks like access to this point is via the [Snug Harbour Trail](https://www.pc.gc.ca/en/pn-np/nl/grosmorne/activ/experiences/randonnee-hiking#P), which leads to the [Northern Traverse](https://www.pc.gc.ca/en/pn-np/nl/grosmorne/activ/experiences/backcountry/northrim).

> From Snug Harbour a rough trail provides access to the mountain plateau and the Northern Traverse.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I’ve been to this cliff. It’s near the western tip of the north side of the fjord. It’s a steep but reasonable day hike up and back from snug cove